# Visual studio 6.0

Tags: visual-studio

I am in need of visual studio 6.0. I have a code base that specifically need to opened using vs 6. I have searced on the web with little success.

Any help of how i can get it on the web will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://www.bing.com/shopping/microsoft-visual-studio-professional-edition-v-6-0/p/B81BDE469D77FCE3A71A?q=buy+Visual+studio+6.0&lpq=buy%20Visual%20studio%206.0&qpvt=buy+Visual+studio+6.0&FORM=HURE

Comment: We won't help you steal software.

Comment: Sometimes when I google: "visual studio 6.0 rapidshare site:blogspot.com" I find illegal copies.  I don't know why they don't get caught.  I think people who use pirated software should be placed in a timeout.

Comment: I would like to add that if anyone downloads those softwares illegally, I hope they have viruses and keyloggers which steal your personal information. I have flagged this as unwelcomed

Answer (score 2):

It's included with many of the [MSDN Subscriptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/buy.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine you tried very hard. There are a [number of retailers](http://www.bing.com/shopping/microsoft-visual-studio-professional-edition-v-6-0/p/B81BDE469D77FCE3A71A?q=buy%20Visual%20studio%206.0&lpq=buy%20Visual%20studio%206.0&qpvt=buy%20Visual%20studio%206.0&FORM=HURE) that sell it online.

Comment: Can't believe they still sell this for 500 $...